# Excel matrix to JSON via Pandas and Numpy.ndarray type

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I am reading a matrix from an excel file. The matrix looks like this:

```
            10100300    10100400    10100500    10100600
10100200    243         0           42          54
10100300    243         23          42          5443
10100400    243         110         42          543
10100500    243         0           432         543232342
10100600    243         440         42          544
10100700    243         0           42          54
```

Ultimately, I wish to convert this to a list of dicts and finally a JSON file.

This would look something like:

```
[{"Origin" : 10100200,
"Destination" : 10100300,
"flow" : 243},
{"Origin" : 10100400,
"Destination" : 10100300,
"flow" : 23}]
```

First, I read this using pandas:
`flows_data_df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")`

Convert to a numpy array:
`flow_data = flows_data_df.as_matrix()`

The matrix is large and has lots of zeros, so I remove them

`clean_flow_data = flow_data[np.all(flow_data == 0, axis=1)]`

At this point, I'm stuck. How do I go from `numpy.ndarray` type to `JSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick to `pandas` which has the `to_dict` method for this, assuming `df` is your original data frame read in from excel, the origins are the index of the data frame and the destinations are the columns of the data frame:

```
(df.stack()[lambda x: x != 0].rename('flow').rename_axis(("Origin", "Destination"))
   .reset_index().to_dict("records"))

#[{'Destination': '10100300', 'Origin': 10100200, 'flow': 243},
# {'Destination': '10100500', 'Origin': 10100200, 'flow': 42},
# {'Destination': '10100600', 'Origin': 10100200, 'flow': 54},
# {'Destination': '10100300', 'Origin': 10100300, 'flow': 243},
# ...
```